Powershell or AzureCLI command to enable Microsoft Defender for SQL
Because I am not allowed to enable Microsoft Defender for SQL from Azure Portal, I am tring to find a Powershell or AzureCLI command to enable it from CloudShell. The final step is to use that command in a pipeline. I am expecting to be a command that get as parameters the name of the server and the group and automatically enable the Microsoft Defender for SQL.
I tried this:
az sql server threat-policy update --resource-group <my-resource-group> --server-name <my-sql-server-name> --state Enabled

The answer was:

'threat-policy' is misspelled or not recognized by the system.

EDIT
After more investigation I have found a partial solution. I will explain bellow:

In the first state the status is disabled: "Enabled status: Disabled"
After I run the following command:

Update-AzSqlServerAdvancedThreatProtectionSetting -Enable $true -ResourceGroupName 'my-resource-group' -ServerName 'my-server-name'

the status was changed to "Enabled status: Enabled at the subscription-level"
and bellow of the status an warning is shown with an "enable" button saying that "SQL Vulnerability Assessment is not configured. Click to enable express configuration".

I would like to have also the "Vulnerability Assesment" enabled in order to have an overview of the findings. I thought this is part of Microsoft Defender for SQL, and enabled it will enable also the "Voulnerability assesment". Are these different?


Note that, the command that you are using is currently deprecated and no longer available. Refer this MS Doc. To enable  Microsoft Defender for SQL, make use of this command az security pricing create -n SqlServers --tier standard

Yes, you need to enable Vulnerability assessment separately after enabling Microsoft Defender for SQL. Refer this MS Doc to manage Vulnerability assessment via Azure PowerShell commands https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/defender-for-cloud/defender-for-sql-on-machines-vulnerability-assessment#manage-vulnerability-assessments-programmatically

Before managing the Vulnerability Assesment programatically I need to Enable it programatically. I am expecting to be something similar to the command I wrote above.

I finally found a solution. I will describe it below:

Activate MICROSOFT DEFENDER FOR SQL using the following command:

Update-AzSqlServerAdvancedThreatProtectionSetting -Enable $true -ResourceGroupName '<your-resource-group-name>' -ServerName '<your-sql-server-name>'


Enable VULNERABILITY ASSESSMENT using the following script

$SubscriptionId = '<your-sub-id>'
$ResourceGroupName = '<your-resoruce-group-name>'
$ServerName = '<your-server-name>'

param
(
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $True)]
    [string]$SubscriptionId,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $True)]
    [string]$ResourceGroupName,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $True)]
    [string]$ServerName,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $False)]
    [switch]$Force
)

function SetSqlVulnerabilityAssessmentServerSetting($SubscriptionId, $ResourceGroupName, $ServerName) {
    $Uri = "/subscriptions/$SubscriptionId/resourceGroups/$ResourceGroupName/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/$ServerName/sqlVulnerabilityAssessments/default?api-version=2022-02-01-preview"
    
    $Body = @{
        properties = @{
            state = "Enabled"
        }
    }

    $Body = $Body | ConvertTo-Json

    return SendRestRequest -Method "Put" -Uri $Uri -Body $Body
}

function SendRestRequest(
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $True)]
    [string] $Method,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $True)]
    [string] $Uri,
    [parameter( Mandatory = $false )]
    [string] $Body = "DEFAULT") {
    $Params = @{
        Method       = $Method
        Path         = $Uri
    }

    if (!($Body -eq "DEFAULT")) {
        $Params = @{
            Method       = $Method
            Path         = $Uri
            Payload      = $Body
        }
    }

    Invoke-AzRestMethod @Params
}

SetSqlVulnerabilityAssessmentServerSetting -SubscriptionId $SubscriptionId -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -ServerName $ServerName


I haven't checked the commands, but their description here in the docs makes me believe that they create and enable Microsoft Defender For SQL. This enables the pricing plan for the entire subscription rather than for an individual resource, as it seems that doing that programmatically might require a POST request to the ARM API.
